# Why does my embedded YouTube video work in Firefox, but not Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, cross-browser, youtube

I'm using the following code to display a YouTube video.

```
<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" 
           value="**URL**">
    </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" 
           value="true">
    </param>
    <embed src="**URL**" 
           type="application/xshockwave-flash" 
           allowfullscreen="true" 
           width="425"
           height="344">
    </embed>
</object>
```

It works in Firefox, but why doesn't it in Internet Explorer?

I'm a totally new to web development, so I'm running into all these wonderful inconsistencies that you veterans are used to ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="VID_URL" width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="VID_URL" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching really hard to find a solution for it and there it is.

Answer (score 8):

To elucidate, it doesn't work because the `object` tag is incomplete. Firefox gives up on the `object` element and uses the fallback old-school `embed` element instead. IE doesn't support `embed` so you get nothing.

An `object` element must at least have a `type` attribute telling it what plugin to use and a `data` attribute telling it what to send the plugin. In IE you also need to mirror the `data` attribute in a `<param name="movie">` value inside the object because it runs plugins differently.

IE won't ‘stream’ partially-loaded Flash files this way though. To get that, you have to use an ActiveX `classid` instead of the `type` to tell it which plugin to use. If you care about this (and you might not: for small files, stub loaders, and files that are useless until complete, it makes no difference) then you have to start serving combinations of nested objects or embeds, which [quickly becomes confusing](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashembedcagematch/).

Answer (score 1):

Previously wasted a few hours working through the same issue. Different cause though...

For IE9, YouTube embeds (at least iframes) were not working because I had previously added Tracking Protection to IE for Google ad servers. In this case, I had to disable the tracking protection (Safety > Tracking Protection) or click the button immediately to the right of the address bar ('Some content is filtered on this site') that alerts end users to filtered content.