# Embedded youtube video in IE9 not working

Tags: internet-explorer, video, youtube, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to embed a youtube video on my site and it doesn't seem to be working in IE.  Seems to work on with other browsers so far.  In IE9, it displays an outline of a box where the video would be with a little red X in the top left corner.

I have tried [Why does my embedded YouTube video work in Firefox, but not Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469250/why-does-my-embedded-youtube-video-work-in-firefox-but-not-internet-explorer) with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using 64 bit IE9?  [According to Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html), they don't support it yet.  There's nothing that you can do to fix it at this point.

Comment: Omg! you're right.  I've been testing using 64-bit IE all this time and didn't realize.  The videos show up just fine in my 32-bit IE.

Answer (score 0):

recently i also faced same problem. but the following code works for me even on 64bit ie.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$query_vars['v'].(($list)?'?list='.$list:'').'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where `$query_vars['v']` is my video id and `$list` is the list id

You need to add embeded version of url when you integrate youtube video.